# Verify a matrix value on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am using MATLAB. I have a question about how i can verify that the values of a matrix are being repeating, like this:

```
A=[ 2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3]
```

If the matrix A repeat at least the first two values for all columns after, i want a AUX = 1. but if not, only AUX= 0.

Comment: Oops, misinterpreted question. Have deleted my answer. Am I understanding correctly that you would like, for example, `AUX = 1` if `A = [2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4]`?

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I want a AUX=1 if A=[ 2 3 2 3 2 3] or A=[ 2 3 2 3 2]. Only matters if the values are repeating, if not, (example: A[ 1 2 3 4 1 2 2 3]) AUX must be =0

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat the first two values for all columns after"? What should be the value of `AUX` for `A = [2 3 3 2]`? What about `A = [2 3 3 3 3 2 3]` or `A = [2 3 4 4 4 2 3]`?

Comment: Thanks. if those kind of values appear, AUX must return 0. Only when the first too columns are repeating AUX must be 1.

Comment: Ah! In that case I've re-instated my answer as I think it is neater and will provide better performance than the answer of @Nirk. Also, can I suggest you edit your question to remove the words "at least" as they are a bit confusing since they suggest patterns such as `[2 3 4 2 3 4]` should result in `AUX = 1`.

Comment: @OscarSantacruz Sorry, the question is still unclear. When you say that `AUX` must be 1 "when the first two columns are repeating", is it possible for other elements to exist? For instance, what about `A = [2 3 2 3 4 2 3]`? Can `[2 3]` be considered repeating here?

Comment: @EitanT The number "4" that you suggest must be considered, so the AUX must be 0.

Comment: @OscarSantacruz So `AUX` would be 1 only in case `A` contains nothing but repetitions of the first two values?

Comment: Yes @EitanT. 

But now i am verifying that my answer can also be A=[ 2 3 3 2 ] or A = [2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2], so i will have to make this part of the program a little bit different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following one-liner works if `A` is a row or column vector, but not necessarily if it is a matrix (thanks to @Dan for providing a simplification in comments). I figured this would be okay since the example you provide in the question is a vector.

```
AUX = ~any(A(3:end) - A(1:end-2))
```

This vectorized solution should be a lot faster than the non-vectorized solution supplied by @Nirk (for large `A`).

Depending on your application you may need to include the error trap:

```
if size(A, 2) < 3; error('Input matrix needs to have at least 3 columns'); end
```

Note, see the comments on this answer for some alternative ways of dealing with the case `size(A, 2) < 3`.

Comment: I think there is an error with your brackeys here - shouldn't your `any` include the `== 0` inside of it? Also if that is the case then this would return `1` erroneously `A=[ 2 3 2 6 7 8 9 0]`

Comment: @Dan I'm not seeing the problem (although I did just notice I had an additional redundant bracket - perhaps that was causing some confusion?). The construct `A(3:end) - A(1:end-2)` will return a non-zero number if, and only if, we don't have a repeating two-column pattern. Also, I plugged your example `A` into my method and it correctly returned `AUX = 0`? Did you mean to write something different?

Comment: OK I see - I misread the question, I thought it should pass for something like A = [2 3 2 3 5], i.e. so long as it repeats at least once. But your (correct) method now could be simplified to this I believe: `AUX = ~any(A(3:end) - A(1:end-2))`

Comment: @Dan Agreed. Adjusting answer now.

Comment: Or perhaps instead of the error, simply allow it: `if numel(A)<3, AUX = 1; end`

Comment: You can use a one-liner: `assert(numel(A) > 2, 'Input matrix must have at least 3 elements')` or shorten Dennis' suggestion: `AUX = AUX || numel(A) < 3;`

Comment: And if the matrix is A=[ 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 2], how can i counter this other way that this matrix can be? I can also have this problem.

Comment: @OscarSantacruz The current solutions will say `AUX` is false in that case. If that is undesirable it becomes a rather different problem (and would I recommend you to ask a new question)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple way to do it:

```
AUX = all(A(1) == A(1:2:end)) && all(A(2) == A(2:2:end))
```

Basically this checks whether all odd elements are equal to the first element, and all even elements are equal to the second element.

Comment: Thanks, the computational time to make this code it's quickly? because i want the best perfomance for this part of it.

Comment: @OscarSantacruz I think Colin's answer is slightly faster (performs only one vectorized comparison), but you need to benchmark both soutions and see for yourself. **Pro tip**: don't try to optimize prematurely if it is not obvious to you. Start worrying about it only when you run into performance issues, profile your program and find the bottleneck.

Comment: thanks for advice, but the problem is that this part of the program must be very quickly because i am using power flow solution already on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to throw in another approach. As I see when you are asking for "repetion" so maybe you want to have the same "pattern" repeated. For this it's easy to abuse the string functions.

```
A=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
position_repetition = strfind(A,A(1:2))
```

I suppose you could use `regexp` for more complicated pattern. Like this would check for the longest pattern that is repeated:

```
tmp = regexp(char(A),'(?<group>.+)\1+','names')
group = double(tmp.group)
```

this should be as I understand the question - it checks if it is a repetion of the first two entries:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
tmp = regexp(char(A),'^(?<group>..)\1+$','names')
AUX = ~isempty(tmp)
```